# Reading multiple data types in a file and storing it in a linked list C++

Tags: c++

how can you read multiple data types in a file and storing it in a linked list. I have the code shown below but it normally reads the file with no linked list but when I used linked list it doesn't work. I think there is something wrong in my code. Programming language: C++ Hope you can help me on how to do this. Thank you

```
struct Video {
int videoID;
string movieTitle;
string movieGenre;
string movieProduction;
int numberOfCopies;};

class videoList {
private:
    struct videoNode {
        Video video;
        struct videoNode *next;
    };
    videoNode *head;

public:
    videoList(); //constructor
    //~videoList(); //deconstructor
    void insertNewVideo (Video vid);
    void rentVideo (Video vid);
    void returnVideo (Video vid);
    void showVideoDetails (Video vid);
    void displayVideo ();
    bool isVideoExist();
    void exit ();
    void generateVideoID();
    void readVideoFile();};

void videoList::readVideoFile () {
videoNode *nodePtr;
ifstream file( "videoList.txt" ) ;
string line ;
string id, movieTitle, movieGenre, movieProduction, numberOfCopies;

if (!file) {
    cout << endl << "\t\t\t\t There is file!" << endl;
}
else {
    std::stringstream linestream(line);
    cout << endl << "\t\t\t\t Movie List " << endl; 
    nodePtr = head;

    while (nodePtr)
        while (getline(file, line)){
{


    std::getline(linestream, id, ',');
    std::getline(linestream, nodePtr->video.movieTitle, ',');
    std::getline(linestream, nodePtr->video.movieGenre, ',');
    std::getline(linestream, nodePtr->video.movieProduction, ',');
    linestream >> nodePtr->video.numberOfCopies;

    if(linestream) // true if there were no errors reading the stream
    {
        std::cout << id << '\n';
        std::cout << nodePtr->video.movieTitle << '\n';
        std::cout << nodePtr->video.movieGenre << '\n';
        std::cout << nodePtr->video.movieProduction << '\n';
        std::cout << nodePtr->video.movieTitle << '\n';
    }
}}}}
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through using a debugger, and confirming the variables and flow of your program behave as you expect them to?

Comment: Note you aren't storing multiple different types in the linked list. You are always storing `Video`. So read the data into a `Video` and store the `Video`.